# CodeIgniter's IPN library - script ignores my code

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using CI IPN library, and as far as their functionality is concerned everything runs smoothly, and all the txn info is committed to the DB, which means that the script is called and runs. 
However, when I try to add my own directives in the case of a successful txn - i.e sending email to the client and adding his details to the DB - It totally ignores my code. I tried to remove the "if successful" condition, and it still doesn't work.
It is important to note that when I run those models outside the IPN controller through a direct call from another controller, they run perfectly.
 Here is the code:

```
    class Ipn extends CI_Controller {

    // To handle the IPN post made by PayPal (uses the Paypal_Lib library).
    public function index()

    {

    $this->load->library('PayPal_IPN'); // Load the library

    // Try to get the IPN data.
    if ($this->paypal_ipn->validateIPN())
    {
        // Succeeded, now let's extract the order
        $this->paypal_ipn->extractOrder();

        // And we save the order now 
        $this->paypal_ipn->saveOrder();

        // Now let's check what the payment status is and act accordingly
        if ($this->paypal_ipn->orderStatus == PayPal_IPN::PAID)
        { 
            $this->load->model("register_model"); // my own code
            $this->register_model->insert(); // my own code
            $this->register_model->email_customer(); //my own code
        } // end if PAID
    } 
    else // Just redirect to the root URL
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        redirect('/', 'refresh');
    } // end if validates
  } // end function
 } // end class
```

TIA for your kind assistance.
Matanya

Comment: try to debug $this->paypal_ipn->orderStatus. btw what are paypal_ipn and orderStatus ?

Comment: paypal_ipn is the name of the library (a class) which was called at the beginning of the script. orderStatus is a method of that class, which returns the status of the order - PAID (i.e. Complete), WAITING(i.e pending) or REJECTED. As I said, even when I removed this condition my code wouldn't run

Answer (score 1):

It can be a bit of a nightmare to debug your Paypal IPN code, I had similar troubles and ended up logging variables within my controller to a file.

Are you sure there isn't a problem with your "register_model" model? Perhaps try adding a few [logs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html), check what variables you are receiving. If it logs and it all looks correct, you need to look at your "register_model" model.